# What is the upper limit on the number of PHP connections to MySQL connections?

Tags: php, mysql

Is the upper limit of the number of connections for the PHP connection database to be placed in the expansion module? Or by the MySQL database itself is determined by the upper limit of the connection.

Asking because the PHP language is not in the code level to build connection pool, so I am very curious about it is how to limit the number of connections, is not and Java in the connection pool is same, in expansion module (PDO MySQL or mysqli) in limiting the maximum number of connections.

Comment: Connections aren't limited in PHP. The MySQL driver or rather MySQL  sets the limit.

Comment: What is ***expansion** module*? Anyway, limiting connections is done by MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Do you mean in the PHP extension? For example, pdo_mysql?

Comment: @dragoste I am referring to the ext of PHP, such as or mysqli or MySQL pdo_mysql

Comment: FYI, *ext* stands from *extension*, not *expansion* ;-)

Comment: @dragoste Forgive my English is not the mother tongue of the Chinese people ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit the number of connections your webserver or php-fpm can handle to less than mysql max_connections setting.
Or raise mysql max_connections setting above the number of connections that your webserver can handle.

Comment: Can you configure this connection number in php-fpm? In which document is it?

Comment: I don't use php-fpm, but it looks like the right setting is pm.max_children.  This option sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served.

Comment: This means that the extension module does not use the connection pool, but by the number of php-fpm child process to limit, I agree with you this statement. Thank you very much!

Comment: I seem to ignore a phenomenon, that is, even if the Pm.max_children children set to 50, theory on the number of connections should not be more than 50, but actual situation is by monitoring database, I found that sometimes the number of connections to far more than 50.

Comment: Do you open only one mysql connection in your code? Other clients like  the one you are using for monitoring are not affected by the limit.